# Group BY Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have two tables:

```
customers(id,first_name,last_name,email)

orders (id,order_date,amount,customer_id)
```

**customer_id in the orders table is the foreign key for id in the customers table**

I'm trying to run the following code on `PostgreSQL` and getting an error:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,order_date, sum(amount) 
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY orders.customer_id;
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate by all the columns in the `select` that are not aggregated.  Also, qualify the column names:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, o.order_date, sum(o.amount) 
FROM customers c INNER JOIN 
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name, o.order_date;
```

If you want the sum per customer name, then remove the `order_date`:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, sum(o.amount) 
FROM customers c INNER JOIN 
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query is ANSI compliant and should run on Postgres without error:

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, SUM(o.amount)
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o
    ON c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I think the immediate cause of the error is that you were also selecting the `order_date` column while aggregating over customers.  This does not make sense, because Postgres has no way of knowing *which* order you are referring to.

Typically it is not possible to select columns in a `GROUP BY` query which either do not appear in the clause itself or are inside an aggregate function such as `MAX` or `SUM`.  However, we can select the customer columns in this case because the `id` functionally determines the values for the first and last names.

Note that if `id` is not a primary key column, then you should use the approach suggested by @Gordon.

### Demo